# Character encoding and types - C/C++

Tags: c, visual-c++

Maybe I have the wrong idea - but it was my understanding that wide types (i.e wchar_t etc) were for UTF-16 Unicode types. If this is correct, then I can't understand the flood of responses to similar issues, all involving some form of wchar_t, or other "wide" conversion with UTF-8.

I'm doing a CLI/C++ project with MSVC, with a Unicode build, that uses an implementation of Luac, to compile lua code to bytecode. Now everything works nicely in that regard, but the trouble is that no special handling is done for UTF-8 files - except for "discarding" the BOM. So all the data within is treated as ANSI. Obviously, when it comes to special characters, it becomes a problem to display them correctly.

So, I need a way to convert between the two - preferably at the source (fopen); but as I've rerouted the output, I could also do so there as well. Unfortunately the only promising solution I've found- using `FILE* fh=fopen(fn,"r,css=UTF-8);` just ends up kicking back an exception for invalid file mode. Which is puzzling, considering it's an Visual C++ project.

Unless of course, I need to change my include order/add an additional include?

```
/lauxlib.c
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "lua.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"    


/lauxlib.h
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lua.h"
```

**Edit:**
After taking a look at the file in a hex editor, I'm beginning to understand. UTF-8 isn't just 1-byte, it's just 1-byte when it *can* be. The initial problem still remains, but at least I understand it a bit more.

**Edit2/Update:**
First off, I'm not sure if this part should be an answer, or if I should close the question - so please, feel free to educate me on that.

The application was originally written to be a console application - so when it needed to output, it just used either putchar or printf. However, this wasn't going to help for a WinForms application. So I basically just rerouted it, by making managed-friendly equivalents.

Luac is essentially a parser/compiler for Lua scripts. It has the option to output information based on the result of that parsing. Listing things like functions, opcodes, constant, and local variables. When it prints out the constants for each function, it prints the actual values of said constants. And that's where the encoding problem comes in.

If the constant value is a string type, the function written to handle printing strings, does the following:

1. casts a its parameter - a pointer to a union type to a const char*
2. loops through the const char* via index, assigning the value of the char to an int
3. checks for any escape characters in the text via a switch/case (tab, newline,etc) and escapes them
4. if that falls through, the default case is checking if it's a printable char, using `isprint`
5. If it is, it uses `putchar`
6. If not, it uses `printf`. Casting it to an unsigned char, and using `\\%03u` for the format.

Now obviously, if the intention was to display it in a form control, and the format is UTF-8, printing out the unsigned value of the individual chars isn't going to help. So I finally decided to just keep Googling for some usage clarification on MultiByteToWideChar, and that worked - except for high value characters (i.e. Asian language characters). Since I found that said Windows function makes some mistakes, I eventually found another that did so "manually". Unfortunately, it still didn't handle those characters correctly.

So I took another look at the actual const char* that was being looped over, and discovered the reason it wasn't being converted - was because something else changed those chars to a value of 63 - the question mark. And this is about the time where tracking that particular "something else" is far beyond my abilities, and asking for help has a real good chance of ending up far too specific for this site's guidelines.

Because the parameter that this function takes, is a pointer to a union typedef, that contains a typedef for string alignment, and a struct - which contains absolutely zero char arrays/pointers. But yet, it casts to one. Which is how that parameter gets turned into a const char* in the function. Since specifically changing certain char values to 63, doesn't seem very beneficial, I'm thinking that it's either the result of a c function, or maybe an ill advised (at least in this case) cast. Maybe if someone knows of a situation where that would be the result, and lets me know, I could probably find the offending code. But otherwise, it's way too specific for me to expect someone to be able to help in this case.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think that `wchar_t` is very useful. I think it was in the C standard before Unicode existed, or just barely after. I've heard that the [ICU library](http://userguide.icu-project.org/) is a good choice for Unicode in C and C++.

Comment: I'm not familiar with MSVC or Luac, but could you explain where in your program it needs to know what the file encoding is? The stdlib string functions just treat strings as a null-terminated array of `char`s. That will work fine for UTF-8 most of the time, as long as you realize that `strlen` will give you the length in bytes rather than the number of Unicode code points. Do you need to convert UTF-8 input to another encoding on output?

Comment: @yellowantphil
Check the Edit2/Update part of the question I just added, I hope that I've explained the situation a bit better - now that I understand it better.

Comment: Read [Joel on Software's The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) and [Unicode, UTF-8 and character encodings: What every developer should know](http://www.teknically-speaking.com/2014/02/unicode-utf-8-and-character-encodings_23.html)

Comment: Cut the prose, show the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Win32 API funxtion `MultibyteToWideChar` to convert the stuff you read to "wide" which is UTF-16.  I think the stream classes and/or FILE streams have a conversion mode, which would be exactly what you need.

wchat_t is a 16-bit UTF-16 code point in Windows. Other platforms often make wchar_t 32 bits and have different conventions.